# allow .NET 2.0 runtime to run executables from network with full trust

Tags: .net, security

Guys, this can't be for real

I'm trying to make a .NET 2.0 executable run from a network drive and it turns out that since Microsoft .net 2.0 has no mscorcfg.msc installed on server 2003, in order to get one I have to install the full SDK. I simply want to run the dang thing without downloading 350Mb piece of crap!

Sorry for rant... Anyone can think of an easy solution?

**EDIT1**: There seems to be a misunderstanding as to what is it that I want to achieve. This is for my test environment. I have many virtual machines and all I want is to just disable the dang security altogether. The task seems to be so trivial, yet it seems so far I have to deploy SDK, or 3.5 SP1, or some other multi-terabyte package to every machine in order to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the security with `caspol.exe`, without needing the msc. However, it would be easier to use ClickOnce deployment ("publish") from VS2005 - this avoids most of the security issues with network shares (but can be hosted **on** a network share).

Comment: I think this is more of a batch processing app. We do that here, where overnight tasks are scheduled on win2003 server but the app itself is required to be physically located on a SAN to ensure backups and whatnot.

Comment: With that said, I guess you could still install a ClickOnce app from a network share and call it via the command line, but it's not as 'clean' on the server machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try running the following command from the .NET command prompt -

**caspol -cg All_Code FullTrust**

This gives the code group 'All_Code' the full set of permissions.

Comment: This worked for me. However one detail work noting is that if you are on a 64 bit computer, there is both framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe and framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe. My application was running as 64 bit, so I needed to run the framework64 version of caspol

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating to .Net 3.5sp1 or later.  That should be capable of running .Net 2.0 code, but they changed the trust system in that version to fix this deployment scenario.

Also, I don't have the link handy, buy you don't need the full SDK to get mscorcfg.msc.  I've seen it included in a much smaller package.  But again, I don't have the link handy and you could google it as easy as I.

Comment: The client profile installer is ~28Mb.  Even if he needs the full 50Mb install, it's a heck of a lot better than a 350Mb SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried caspol.exe?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(VS.80).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx

Comment: caspol.exe is also not included in .net and requires SDK as far as I know, but yea, at least i can just copy and run it

Answer (score -1):

Caveat: I might not understand your question since I don't understand the reference to mscorcfg.msc. Is .NET installed or not on the machine?

If it is, the easy solution:

1. Configure security to allow you to run the program from the network share

If it isn't, the easy solution:

1. Install .NET runtime

---

Sorry to be so blunt that really is the easy solution.

Other solutions involve:

- Packaging up your program into a .EXE file with the relevant pieces of the .NET runtime in it. This packaging requires specialized software to do this, and these doesn't come cheap, although the exact names of these tools escape me.
- Rewrite the program to not use .NET

Comment: This is the application I was talking about: http://vvcap.net/db/Ew2So6LJAPCXGdxb3Bc6.htp . It is not supplied with .NET 2.0, you must install SDK in order to get it.